# Percentage increase of 3% or percentage increment of 3%

Tags: word-choice

I'm drafting a research paper and I'm not sure about the correct form in this context, please

Comment: You're talking about "in this context" but you've not really given any useful context.

Comment: Using *percentage* in an expression with *%* is redundant. Just say *an increase of 3%*.